# How to access PHP, MYSQL localhost database on android actual device

Tags: php, android, mysql

my android project based on php, mysql database, when i run in my actual device which is google nexus7 the application running without any error messages, but im not able to access the database files which in my pc localhost wamp server.

Comment: Android project based on php o_0

Comment: Your web server is running on an Android device? Can you give more details?

Comment: i just install wamp server and create database in phpmyadmin and also upload all the files (config.php, dbconnect.php, get_categories.php, new_category.php)  inside the www directry and call these in my android Mainactivity.java then i run my application in actual device i can view all the ui design but im not able to access that database files .  this my Mainactivity.java file  // Url to create new categoryprivate String URL_NEW_CATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/food_api/new_category.php";// Url to get all categoriesprivate String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://10.0.2.2/food_api/get_categories.php";

Answer (score 0):

Local host means, by definition, you can only access it from that machine. That's why it is local.

Access the server via a local network or build an actual website.